# In new laravel app installing laravel/ui I have no Register and Login links

Tags: laravel, authentication

I installed new laravel app with command

```
laravel new PassportTest
```

and next I installed auth

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

but running server with command

```
php artisan serve
```

and opening in my browser url :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

I do not have Register and Login links at right top corner.

In my composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
},
```

And In config/auth.php I have :

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],


'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

and:

```
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 7.9.2
```

and looking at the last output I wonder why such big version?
Looks like just half of an year ago I had 6 version as a new branch...

Can it be the key of my problem or what did I miss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frontend scaffolding that Laravel provides is generated depending on what frontend framework you want to use. `composer require laravel/ui` brings in the package itself, to actually install the frontend framework scaffolding you need to specify which frontend framework you want to use with **one** of the following commands:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

Also, Laravel now uses  [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/), which means you'll most likely see a completely new major version every 6 months. The version increments will be much faster than before.